# The UA Mage of Lorehold's Ancient Companion (Healer) has the Healer's Light action; do those temp HP remain if you bond to a different spirit type?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, duration, temporary-hit-points

In the UA of [Mages of Strixhaven](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/strixhaven), the Mage of Lorehold's Ancient Companion feature lets you bond to a spirit when you finish a short or long rest, choosing Healer, Sage, or Warrior.

If Healer is chosen, the Ancient Companion has the following action:

> ***Healer’s Light (Healer Only).*** The companion chooses a creature it can see within 15 feet of itself and flares with invigorating light. The creature gains 1d8 + PB temporary hit points.

When you use a short rest to bond to a different type of Ancient Companion spirit (Sage or Warrior), do the temporary HP remain on whomever they were given to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The temporary hit points would remain

They would remain, as per the general rules for [temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints). These are given in chapter 9 of the *Player’s Handbook* and *Basic Rules*, at the end of the section on damage and healing. The very last paragraph about temporary hit points states:

> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they're depleted or you finish a long rest.

This feature does not list a duration, so the temporary hit points last until the target loses them (by taking damage) or finishes a long rest.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @V2Blast!